# Firebase SDK signInWithPopup() not working with Electron

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

I have an electron app that fires up a lightweight `express` server allowing me to use `http` in production for `firebase` github authentication.

I have this working fine using the `signInWithRedirect()` firebase auth method. However, i cannot get the `signInWithPopup()` method to work.

A new `electron` window launches, but the content is blank. Does my electron entry file need configuring for the above to work as expected?

This is working fine when i launch the app in a regular browser window which leads me to think electron needs configuring...

Comment: I am also facing this problem

Comment: I ended up setting the `nativeWindowOpen` property on the main `BrowserWindow` object to `true` which seemed to solve it. However, i later ran into a couple of additional issues so i ended up getting the github token manually (opening my own pop up) and using `SignInWithCredentials`